# UITapGestureRecognizer not attaching action

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I created a separate class for View.
I left all the functions in the Controller.
But when I add a click on the picture, it doesn't work for some reason.

```swift
import UIKit

class APOTDView: UIView {

    var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(APOTDViewController.imageTapped(_:)))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        return imageView
    }()
}
```

```swift
import UIKit

class APOTDViewController: UIViewController {

    let av = APOTDView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ... add subview and constraint
    }

    @objc func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("good job")
    }
}
```

What's the matter? Please help me figure it out

Comment: try with signature
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    // handling code
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector in the UITapGestureRecognizer is wrong. You can not call the APOTDViewController directly.
APOTDViewController.imageTapped would be a static function, which is not available.

You can use a delegate instead.

Delegate Protocol and View.

```
protocol APOTDViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func viewDidTapImage()
}

class APOTDView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: APOTDViewDelegate?

    var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        return imageView
    }()

    @objc func imageTapped() {
        delegate?.viewDidTapImage()
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class APOTDViewController: UIViewController, APOTDViewDelegate {
    let av = APOTDView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        av.delegate = self
        // ... add subview and constraint
    }

    @objc func viewDidTapImage() {
        print("good job")
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Are you definitely not mistaken?

Comment: @egorskikh try to remove @objc from view controller class function. like this ```func viewDidTapImage() {
        print("good job")
    }```

Comment: @RajaKishan It doesn't work for me anyway ... I tried your answer too. And nothing comes out

Comment: Then problem is in your code. I tested and after posted. Please review your code again

Comment: @RajaKishan Thank you. I will look for a problem. Although everything is written as written florieger

Comment: @egorskikh Are you adding the imageView to APOTDView somewhere? Are you using Storyboards or how is the rest of your setup?

Comment: @florieger the code that I have not shown here:

Comment: `view.addSubview(av.imageView)`

Comment: `av.imageView.topAnchor.constraint... `

Comment: @florieger I do everything through the code

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, because you are calling the `UIViewController` method directly without any class reference or object. The solution is to use protocol or clouser to get action from view to class.

class

```
class APOTDView: UIView {
    @objc var imageViewAction: ((UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)? = nil
    
    lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.backgroundColor = .blue
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector((imageTapped(_:))))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        return imageView
    }()
    
    @objc private func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.imageViewAction?(sender)
    }
}
```

ViewController

```
class APOTDViewController: UIViewController {
    let av = APOTDView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        av.imageViewAction = { sender in
            print("good job")
        }
    }
}
```