# Swift - Unrecognized Selector to instance - UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to set up a `UITapGestureRecognizer` but I keep having the following error :

> [projet.View tapA]:] unrecognized selector sent to instance *adress*

Here's my code :

Class View :

```
class View: UIView {

     init(frame: CGRect, s: TimeInterval, position : CGPoint , size : CGSize) {

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:   
        #selector(ViewController.tapA(sender:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
     }
}
```

Class ViewController (UIViewController) :

```
@objc func tapA (sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        //For now : 
        print("Jump")
   }
```

I haven't been able to find any problems like this one.
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The method is in `ViewController`, so it's an instance of `ViewController` that implements that method. BUT you do `UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self`, so the target is `self`, the instance of View `itself`. Since it doesn't know that method, it crash with that error message.

Comment: You can not use a direct selector by this. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65736298/14733292

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the selector in the `ViewController` class, create it in the `View` class
and pass an instance of the view controller to it, then in the selector just execute the code
of the `ViewController`:

**View**

```
class View: UIView {

     var viewController: ViewController!

     init(frame: CGRect, s: TimeInterval, position : CGPoint , size : CGSize) {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapA(_:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
     }

     @objc 
     private func tapA(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let vc = viewController as? ViewController else { return }
        vc.execTapA()
     }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
func execTapA() {
    // Execute the code you need
}
```

To pass the reference of `ViewController` to the view just call, in your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method:

```
view.viewController = self
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally used `self.view` instead of `self`

```swift
// Wrong
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(dismissVC))

// Correct
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissVC))
```